# Running code on selected sheet rather than active sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am setting my ws variable to the first worksheet but my code runs on the active sheet.

This code runs from a button on Sheet2 and I am using `Sheets(1).Select` as the name of the first worksheet can vary.

What do I need to change so that my code runs on Sheets(1)?

```
Function Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lColumn As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim myRange As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set ws = Sheets(1)

    With ws
        lColumn = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

        colName = Split(Worksheets(1).Cells(1, lColumn).Address, "$")(1)

        Range("A1: " & colName & "1").Font.Bold = True

        Set myRange = Range("A1: " & colName & "1")

        For Each cell In myRange
            cell.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
            cell.Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            cell.Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            cell.Interior.TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
            cell.Interior.PatternTintAndShade = 0
        Next

    End with

End Function
```

Comment: This should be a runtime error 424 on `Set ws = Sheets(1).Select` because `Select` doesn't ***return*** anything. Change that line to `Set ws = Sheets(1)`

Comment: @Comintern - Set ws = Sheets(1) still the same outcome - the changes are made to active sheet

Comment: Is this the actual code? If it is, it should do something - namely throw a run-time error.

Comment: @Comintern - yes I made the edit you stated and copy/pasted into my workbook and the sheet with the button is the sheet that the code formats

Comment: OK, then all you should need to do is add a `.` in front of all the `Range` and `Cells` references inside the `With` block. You aren't using the `With` at all.

Comment: Ah - since I did not actually add the `.` my `With ws` syntax wasn't actually setting anything.  Thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `With` statements, you still need to prefix `.` in front of the properties, so that the member call is made against the `With` block variable.

I changed `lColumn = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count` to `lColumn = .UsedRange.Columns.Count`

```
.Range("A1: " & colName & "1").Font.Bold = True
Set myRange = .Range("A1: " & colName & "1")
```

by not using the `.` VBA thinks you are referencing the `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: You thought is correct although this was already established in comments by @Comintern :)

Comment: @urdearboy eh, *he who answers in comments, donates their wisdom to whomever grabs it and puts it in an actual upvoteable answer* ;-)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon always with the words of wisdom <3

Comment: @urdearboy - I couldn't find the dup target that I was looking for fast enough.